# Killer removed from castMembers array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, variables

I am trying to have a function choose 1 person in the Cast Members Array to be the killer for the game and once that killer is picked, it will remove that killer from the castMember player array.

So the killer is removed from the survivors array and added as their own variable to call for future functions

I tried to use a for loop and splice the killer from the array, but it's not working.

````
let episodes = 6; // Episode count
let episodecount = 0; // Episode Value count
let killer; // Initializes killer variable
let killerRevealed = false; // Initializes killerRevealed variable
let stamina; // Stamina stat for each player 
let speed; // Speed stat for each player 
let strength; // Strength stat for each player 
let suspicion; // Suspicion stat for each player 
let highestPlayer; //Highest stat player

let castMembers = [
"Sidney Prescott",
"Gale Weathers",
"Stu Macher",
"Billy Loomis",
"Dewey Riley",
"Tatum Riley",
"Principal Himbry",
"Kenny Brown"
];

let gameStarted = false;
let objects = ["knife", "gun", "shovel", "rope", "candle", "matche", "lighter", "clothesline", "hiding spot", "clue"]; // List of objects 
let events = ["sudden outburst", "false accusation", "heated argument", "suspicious behavior", "mysterious disappearance", "surprising discovery"]; // List of random events
let scenes = ["opening scene", "house party garage scene", "outside van scene", "high school scene", "house party living room", "house party attick"]
let playAs1996Cast = document.getElementById("buttonp")
let killerSet = false;


function getRandom(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

// Function to randomly select the Killer 
function chooseKiller(){
    
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * castMembers.length);
    killer = castMembers[randomNumber];

    console.log ("A new killer has been chosen: " + killer);
    
    
    for (var i = 0; i < killer.length; i++){
        if (killer[i].id == 1) {
            killer.splice(i, 1)
            break;
        }
    }```
````

Comment: "but it's not working" - be more specific. What isn't happening that should? What is happening that shouldn't? What, if any, console errors do you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to filter the killer out  of the castMembers array

```
 castMembers = castMembers.filter(x => x!== killer);
```

Note that the original aray will be mutated until the page is refreshed. If you don't want that - then you can just create a new array

```
 let filteredCastMembers;
 ...

 filteredCastMembers= castMembers.filter(x => x!== killer);
```

```js
let episodes = 6; // Episode count
let episodecount = 0; // Episode Value count
let killer; // Initializes killer variable
let killerRevealed = false; // Initializes killerRevealed variable
let stamina; // Stamina stat for each player 
let speed; // Speed stat for each player 
let strength; // Strength stat for each player 
let suspicion; // Suspicion stat for each player 
let highestPlayer; //Highest stat player

let castMembers = [
"Sidney Prescott",
"Gale Weathers",
"Stu Macher",
"Billy Loomis",
"Dewey Riley",
"Tatum Riley",
"Principal Himbry",
"Kenny Brown"
];

let gameStarted = false;
let objects = ["knife", "gun", "shovel", "rope", "candle", "matche", "lighter", "clothesline", "hiding spot", "clue"]; // List of objects 
let events = ["sudden outburst", "false accusation", "heated argument", "suspicious behavior", "mysterious disappearance", "surprising discovery"]; // List of random events
let scenes = ["opening scene", "house party garage scene", "outside van scene", "high school scene", "house party living room", "house party attick"]
let playAs1996Cast = document.getElementById("buttonp")
let killerSet = false;


function getRandom(arr) {
    return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

// Function to randomly select the Killer 
function chooseKiller(){
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * castMembers.length);
    killer = castMembers[randomNumber];
    console.log ("A new killer has been chosen: " + killer);
    castMembers = castMembers.filter(x => x!== killer);
    console.log (castMembers); //gives all cast members apart from the killer
 }
 
getRandom(castMembers);
chooseKiller();//consoles all cast members apart from the killer
```

Comment: I appreciate the support on this, it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the loop. Just use `splice` to get the killer since `splice` will mutate the original array and return the spliced item.

Also, I didn't see your call of the `chooseKiller` function.

```
// ... setup above ...

function chooseKiller() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * castMembers.length);

  // using .pop() since it will return an array so this gets the actual value
  killer = castMembers.splice(randomNumber, 1).pop();

  console.log(`A killer has been chosen: ${killer}`);
  console.log(`Cast members are now: ${castMembers.join(", ")}`);
}

chooseKiller();
```

If you don't wish to mutate the original array, you should use the `filter` method as suggested in other answers. Not mutating can be useful to run the `chooseKiller` function again without having to reset the variables to the initial values.

Comment: Thanks for helping on this, I appreciate the comments explaining as well, really helpful.